# How to Pick which Framework Version to Build app for C# Visualstudio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am very new to C# development. Like Youtube tutorial new. I am trying to build a console app to install services to our servers. Is there a way to pick which .Net version you want to use to build the application? So that I the writer can tell the user which .Net version they should have in their system for the console app to run?

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: The newest one will do.  .NET Core is the direction Microsoft is headed.

Comment: It depends, which OS do the servers run? If they support .NET Framework 4.8, go with that, otherwise go with the latest version those OSes support (assuming you want to use .NET Framework specifically)

Comment: Why is this question unclear?  It's a simple question with a simple answer: You set the Target Framework in the Project Properties.  But the Project Type determines whether you're targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft because I just told you, I came off a youtube tutorial. I see the lack of sympathy on these forums are strong. Not even in my classes have they talked about project compilation. I have never written a full C# program before. Honestly I'm even sorry I asked. Most of you expect someone to know what you know apparently

Comment: I'm agreeing with you.  This is a fine question, and shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Are soory about that. I thought you were asking me why it wasn't clear for me on what to do. Yeah I don't get it either. This is something our professor hasn't talked about. I'm on an internship and I am the only one on my team that has to do this. Most of the team uses python. I appreciate your sympathy. This is something even the youtube tutorials don't cover

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft When i made my console app, it didn't ask me which Framework to use. I clicked on consle app template it launched me straight to the program. After I built it, I realized I have no idea which framework its using. It shows netcoreapp 3.1 however. I have no idea how I got here

Comment: _"When i made my console app, it didn't ask me which Framework to use"_ - it does though. If you create a new project and search for "Console Application", you get to choose between "Console Application (.NET Core)" and "Console Application (.NET Framework)".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David Browne's comment under my original post all you need to do is make sure to select .Net Framework version of the Console Application template in Visual Studio project template. Not .Net Core. I wasn't aware there was a difference:

"You set the Target Framework in the Project Properties. But the Project Type determines whether you're targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core"

Comment: And here's the doc on how .NET Framework versions map to Windows versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#:~:text=Detect%20.NET%20Framework%204.5%20and%20later%20versions%20,other%20Windo%20...%20%206%20more%20rows%20

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to get started

.NET Framework - Apps build using .NET framework can only run on Windows. This is an years old proven and secure stable, mature eco system

.NET Core - Apps build using .NET Core can run on Windows, Linux and Mac. It's cross platform and open source. Latest is v5.0.

I recommend you to use the latest .NET Core v5 for your new projects. It's stable and Microsoft is well supporting it. .NET Core much is powerful, faster and optimized.

You can create different kinds of apps using .NET Core. You can create simple console apps, libraries or asp.net core web apps. MVC and WebAPI are supported. As you mentioned, if you want to create a service, There is "Worker Service" project available for .NET Core.
If you create a Worker Service it can run as a Windows Service in Windows machines and a Linux Deamon in Linux machines.

Visual Studio 2019 got well with .NET Core and it's features.

If you need to run a .NET Core project in Windows, Linux or Mac machine, you also need to setup the deployment machine installed with .NET Core runtime. It's available free from Microsoft website. Download.. Install.. Run. That simple

Comment: You can also deploy a .Net Core app as a single self-contained executable for a particular platform with no need to install .NET Core on the target machine.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/  in Visual Studio, you do this with the Project/Publish dialog.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks, I'll look into it. That is the one thing in my very brief peek into .net that I don't like. That I have to have folder of other files in other for the .exe to run. Is this only a netcore issue or also a .Net issue?

Comment: This capability is new in .NET Core.  Although for .NET Framework you can deploy just an .exe so long as you don't need any external libraries outside of the .NET Framework.